# Pandas Merge two rows into a single row based on columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have 2 rows that look like these,

```
------------------------------
DealName | Target | Acquirer |
-----------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | None     |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | None   | XYZ      |
------------------------------
```

I'm looking to merge them into a single as:

```
------------------------------
DealName | Target | Acquirer |
-----------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | XYZ      |
------------------------------
```

Not sure how to accomplish this in Pandas. Any pointers will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.replace('None','').groupby('DealName',as_index=False).agg(''.join)
Out[25]: 
  DealName Target Acquirer
0  ABC-XYZ    ABC      XYZ
```

Comment: `df.replace('None','').groupby(['DealName'], as_index=False).agg('sum')`

Comment: Thanks. Would this work if there's another 10 columns and some of them might be None?